# location.lat is not a function

Tags: google-maps, unit-testing, autocomplete, google-places-api, google-places

I'm trying to write a unit test for `getAddress()` a function that gets the address from a `google.maps.places.autocomplete`. To trigger the function I need to set a new place programmatically because the `place_changed` event handler calls `getAddress()`. When setting a place using the GUI `location.lat` is a function and when doing programmatically it is a property.

So to set a new place I do this:

```
let place = { "address_components": [{ "long_name": "Auckland", "short_name": "Auckland", "types": ["locality", "political"] }, { "long_name": "Auckland", "short_name": "Auckland", "types": ["administrative_area_level_2", "political"] }, { "long_name": "Auckland", "short_name": "Auckland", "types": ["administrative_area_level_1", "political"] }, { "long_name": "New Zealand", "short_name": "NZ", "types": ["country", "political"] }], "adr_address": "<span class=\"locality\">Auckland</span>, <span class=\"country-name\">New Zealand</span>", "formatted_address": "Auckland, New Zealand", "geometry": { "location": { "lat": -36.8484597, "lng": 174.76333150000005 }, "viewport": { "south": -37.0654751, "west": 174.44380160000003, "north": -36.660571, "east": 175.2871371 } }, "icon": "https://maps.gstatic.com/mapfiles/place_api/icons/geocode-71.png", "id": "088418ddc17fef2513462d92dbee1355929b35ed", "name": "Auckland", "photos": [{ "height": 1836, "html_attributions": ["<a href=\"https://maps.google.com/maps/contrib/111644522305605838507/photos\">Johannes De Smedt</a>"], "width": 3264 }, { "height": 2988, "html_attributions": ["<a href=\"https://maps.google.com/maps/contrib/104449230804367883642/photos\">Michal Panek</a>"], "width": 5312 }, { "height": 3096, "html_attributions": ["<a href=\"https://maps.google.com/maps/contrib/115717451821958551526/photos\">Sakchhyam Malla</a>"], "width": 4128 }, { "height": 3672, "html_attributions": ["<a href=\"https://maps.google.com/maps/contrib/100726048745034015308/photos\">Maria Bitunjac</a>"], "width": 4896 }, { "height": 1836, "html_attributions": ["<a href=\"https://maps.google.com/maps/contrib/112349734260069492163/photos\">Carol Prichard</a>"], "width": 3264 }, { "height": 3120, "html_attributions": ["<a href=\"https://maps.google.com/maps/contrib/106356366323887392782/photos\">Kovács György</a>"], "width": 4208 }, { "height": 1504, "html_attributions": ["<a href=\"https://maps.google.com/maps/contrib/117137027694384717244/photos\">Martin Mobers</a>"], "width": 2006 }, { "height": 492, "html_attributions": ["<a href=\"https://maps.google.com/maps/contrib/102033645464260143092/photos\">Priyesh Bhavsar</a>"], "width": 1000 }, { "height": 2988, "html_attributions": ["<a href=\"https://maps.google.com/maps/contrib/103221298159348509467/photos\">Alvie Granito</a>"], "width": 5312 }, { "height": 3265, "html_attributions": ["<a href=\"https://maps.google.com/maps/contrib/100418135834547049744/photos\">Simon Chen</a>"], "width": 4898 }], "place_id": "ChIJ--acWvtHDW0RF5miQ2HvAAU", "reference": "CmRbAAAAEJGwhQ0l3O1QapXvbJ_s-xNVyh7UxBjd89D9Q860dfhb5Xh3xeY95UT1tIdugiTRhhZHT2qk_wzUqfd3wPS-vdX1pBljxcPtMUqhTtslzMyVccViA9ckk50Xv_cFWNXFEhCPkvW84Okrk2SJUpUDLGz8GhSEN1dm_0tJj4nEHYo0-bkRdOykYQ", "scope": "GOOGLE", "types": ["locality", "political"], "url": "https://maps.google.com/?q=Auckland,+New+Zealand&ftid=0x6d0d47fb5a9ce6fb:0x500ef6143a29917", "utc_offset": 780, "vicinity": "Auckland" }

        testHost.areaPicker.autocomplete.set("place", place);
```

regarding my place variable I get this compile time error:

> '"adr_address"' does not exist in type 'PlaceResult'.

However when I do this, for some reason the resulting place object's `geometry.lat` and `geometry.lng` are no longer functions but now they are properties.

But when I use the autocomplete in real scenarios they are functions. As they should be. How do I get them to be functions in my unit test? Full code below.

Unit test:

```
it('EmitAreaChanged_AreaEntered_AreaPlaceValueMakesItToHost', () => {
        let place = { "address_components": [{ "long_name": "Auckland", "short_name": "Auckland", "types": ["locality", "political"] }, { "long_name": "Auckland", "short_name": "Auckland", "types": ["administrative_area_level_2", "political"] }, { "long_name": "Auckland", "short_name": "Auckland", "types": ["administrative_area_level_1", "political"] }, { "long_name": "New Zealand", "short_name": "NZ", "types": ["country", "political"] }], "adr_address": "<span class=\"locality\">Auckland</span>, <span class=\"country-name\">New Zealand</span>", "formatted_address": "Auckland, New Zealand", "geometry": { "location": { "lat": -36.8484597, "lng": 174.76333150000005 }, "viewport": { "south": -37.0654751, "west": 174.44380160000003, "north": -36.660571, "east": 175.2871371 } }, "icon": "https://maps.gstatic.com/mapfiles/place_api/icons/geocode-71.png", "id": "088418ddc17fef2513462d92dbee1355929b35ed", "name": "Auckland", "photos": [{ "height": 1836, "html_attributions": ["<a href=\"https://maps.google.com/maps/contrib/111644522305605838507/photos\">Johannes De Smedt</a>"], "width": 3264 }, { "height": 2988, "html_attributions": ["<a href=\"https://maps.google.com/maps/contrib/104449230804367883642/photos\">Michal Panek</a>"], "width": 5312 }, { "height": 3096, "html_attributions": ["<a href=\"https://maps.google.com/maps/contrib/115717451821958551526/photos\">Sakchhyam Malla</a>"], "width": 4128 }, { "height": 3672, "html_attributions": ["<a href=\"https://maps.google.com/maps/contrib/100726048745034015308/photos\">Maria Bitunjac</a>"], "width": 4896 }, { "height": 1836, "html_attributions": ["<a href=\"https://maps.google.com/maps/contrib/112349734260069492163/photos\">Carol Prichard</a>"], "width": 3264 }, { "height": 3120, "html_attributions": ["<a href=\"https://maps.google.com/maps/contrib/106356366323887392782/photos\">Kovács György</a>"], "width": 4208 }, { "height": 1504, "html_attributions": ["<a href=\"https://maps.google.com/maps/contrib/117137027694384717244/photos\">Martin Mobers</a>"], "width": 2006 }, { "height": 492, "html_attributions": ["<a href=\"https://maps.google.com/maps/contrib/102033645464260143092/photos\">Priyesh Bhavsar</a>"], "width": 1000 }, { "height": 2988, "html_attributions": ["<a href=\"https://maps.google.com/maps/contrib/103221298159348509467/photos\">Alvie Granito</a>"], "width": 5312 }, { "height": 3265, "html_attributions": ["<a href=\"https://maps.google.com/maps/contrib/100418135834547049744/photos\">Simon Chen</a>"], "width": 4898 }], "place_id": "ChIJ--acWvtHDW0RF5miQ2HvAAU", "reference": "CmRbAAAAEJGwhQ0l3O1QapXvbJ_s-xNVyh7UxBjd89D9Q860dfhb5Xh3xeY95UT1tIdugiTRhhZHT2qk_wzUqfd3wPS-vdX1pBljxcPtMUqhTtslzMyVccViA9ckk50Xv_cFWNXFEhCPkvW84Okrk2SJUpUDLGz8GhSEN1dm_0tJj4nEHYo0-bkRdOykYQ", "scope": "GOOGLE", "types": ["locality", "political"], "url": "https://maps.google.com/?q=Auckland,+New+Zealand&ftid=0x6d0d47fb5a9ce6fb:0x500ef6143a29917", "utc_offset": 780, "vicinity": "Auckland" }

        testHost.areaPicker.autocomplete.set("place", place);
        expect(testHost.placeValue).toBe(true);
    });
```

relevant part of my component under test that uses a google autocomplete:

```
ngAfterViewInit() {
    this.autocomplete = new google.maps.places.Autocomplete(
        <HTMLInputElement>this.areaInput.nativeElement, this._options);
  this.autocomplete.addListener('place_changed', () => {
        this.getAddress(this.autocomplete)
    });
    this.areaInput.nativeElement.setCustomValidity("");
}

public getAddress(autocomplete: google.maps.places.Autocomplete): void {
    if (this._canGetAddress) {
        var place: google.maps.places.PlaceResult = autocomplete.getPlace();
        this.address = place['formatted_address'];
        var location = place['geometry']['location'];
        var lat = location.lat();
        var lng = location.lng();
        this.onAreaChanged.emit({areaEntered: true, place: place});
        this.areaInput.nativeElement.setCustomValidity("");
    }
}
```

Here is my code I want to test:

```
    public getAddress(autocomplete: google.maps.places.Autocomplete): void {
        if (this._canGetAddress) {
            var place: google.maps.places.PlaceResult = autocomplete.getPlace();
            this.address = place['formatted_address'];
            var location = place['geometry']['location'];
            var lat = location.lat();
            var lng = location.lng();
            this.onAreaChanged.emit({areaEntered: true, place: place});
            this.areaInput.nativeElement.setCustomValidity("");
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

The location needs to be a `google.maps.LatLng` object.

Comment: How do I make it be that? I'm just using the resulting `google.maps.places.PlaceResult` from `autocomplete.getPlace()`